# Picasa text tag and google plus

Tags: google-plus, picasa

I'm trying to find text tags that i used in my picasa web album photos, on google plus albums. I have tried to search typing some tags in the search bar of google plus but it seems that picasa web text tags aren't considered, only descriptions.

How i can solve this problem?Can anyone help me?How i can find text tags on google plus photos?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you can only see the tags in the image properties of the picasa version of the album (picasaweb.google.com), but if you search for a known tag in google plus photos it does filter on tags.  I too could not find the tag listed anywhere in google plus photos.